# Como quitar líneas naranjas de VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio

estoy utilizando VSCode para un proyecto con React pero me es muy molesto trabajar con esas líneas de colores en el código cuando hay algún error. Alguien sabe el acceso directo/indirecto para cambiarlas por algo menos molesto  o que no sea tan invasivo? Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es algo propio del tema/configuración de colores o sucede independientemente de esta configuración?

Comment: nunca vi esas lineas.. sera un addin que pusiste?

Comment: Deduzco que al ser un tema de tipo "alto contraste" puede que el selector de línea haya cambiado sus colores. VSCode tiene por defecto un selector de realce de color cuando se selecciona una línea

Comment: Tienes razón KBeDev, es el tema "alto contraste", ya lo he cambiado y está solucionado, gracias!